# Make Text Stretch 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I said this *might* be possible to my client, and i said I'd research it and let him know. Anyways, with JS or a CSS hack, is it possible to make text stretch 100% of the window? What i mean by this is, how can I make the title of his site, no matter the window size, fit exactly 100% inside the window by dynamically changing the font size to equal the same width?

I'm currently attempting to make a hidden span with a O inside and dynamically pulling the size of the span holding the O and seeing if it changes and if so resizes the font based on some specific size. It's super hacky, and isn't bulletproof, so that's why Im asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lay it out as a `<span>` without consideration for the Window width; after it loads, query the element's width, and scale the font-size up by windowwidth/spanwidth (to avoid rounding issues, multiply the default font size by windowwidth, then divide the result by spanwidth, or doing everything using floating-point arithmetic).

Comment: Worked! I did the window.width/span.width+'em';

Answer (score 0):

This all sounds like allot of work for little gain but the only way that comes to my mind is, you could first detect screen size with javascript and build a style sheet for each?

But will kind of all get messy if user resizes screen.